# Is there a way to disconnect running KVM session in Intel Manageability Commander

Tags: kvm-switch

My team uses IMC to get Windows machine status from the user's perspective via KVM sessions.
We run into issues where we can't make a KVM connection because someone walked away or, for whatever reason does not disconnect their session.
It seems IMC only allows one KVM session at a time, so it's unavailable until whatever the timeout period is.
Is there a way to remotely disconnect a running KVM/IMC connection or maybe an alternate solution?

Comment: What version of Intel Manageability Commander are you running? The manual mentions nothing of multiple sessions which suggests it isn’t supported

Comment: @Ramhound Version 1.0.8

Comment: Current version is 2.4